# Usage of the command "pdftex [OPTION] ... \FIRST-LINE"

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I'm novice TeX user who inherited 100 **plain TeX** files that I want to convert to PDF. I installed TeX Live 2013 on a Mac to do so.

Before converting to PDF I would like to add each TeX file's date and time to the resulting PDF.  I assumed that the **\FIRST-LINE** argument would allow me to do so since according to pdftex usage:

###### pdftex [OPTION] ...  \FIRST-LINE

###### if the first non-option argument begins with a backslash, interpret all non-option arguments as a line of pdfTeX input

First I created a simple plain TeX file to test:

```
\hbox{HEADLINE}
\line{{Amortization computations}  \hfil{10/10/03}}
\bye
```

I then tested this command under bash:

> pdftek test.tex '\line{hello}'

but the \line argument is ignored even though it appears in the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdftex 2013.8.12)  15 JUL 2023 16:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex \line{FIRST}
(./test.tex [1{/usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/p
dftex.map}] )</usr/local/texlive/2013basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 14734 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

If I manually insert **\line{hello}** as the first line of the file, the resulting PDF does show "hello".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

If you want that `\line{hello}` appears at the beginning, you need to use `\input`, otherwise it's appended at the end (but `\bye` in the file will make TeX to ignore it).

```bash
pdftex '\line{hello}\input{test}'
```

will produce

[image]

(with an underfull box message).

Comment: Thanks @egreg for the explanation.  However on my system it produces an error: ``! I can't find file ``{test}'.`
However I discovered that `pdftex '\line{hello}\input test.tex'` does work.

Comment: @apta Yes, for older TeX distributions you need to remove the braces around the file name.